# nextjs correct folder structure and dynamic routing

Tags: next.js, directory-structure

So i have this Link which passing a href

```
   {
      name: "Action",
      cell: (row) => (
        <div className="flex items-center space-x-5">
          <Link href={`/members/${row.id}/edit`}>Edit</Link>
          <button>delete</button>
        </div>
      ),
    },
```

then if i click that it is normally should show 404, but when i add a page to catch the link href it should show something

in reactjs it use this code
`<Route path="/members/:id/edit" element={<ExampleName>}`
[image]

how can i achieve this in next js?

i will attach image contains the folder structure of my nextjs

[image: folderstructure]

i am expecting it to show a page and at the same the links in browser should be correct.

I am self learning only and just reading documentation, but i still get confuse.

TIA

Comment: file called `page.jsx` in `app/members/[id]/edit` folder will show for these URLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your image above, for this route `/members/[id]/edit` in NextJs 13 the folder structure is like this

```
/app
  /members
    /[id]
      /edit
        page.tsx
      layout.tsx
      page.tsx
    layout.tsx
    page.tsx
  layout.tsx
  page.tsx
```

You also need to know more about the [route group](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups) if later I assume that the member has more than 1 rights, like edit and delete